# Cannot create SPEC file with sepolicy-generate

Tags: selinux

In EL7 I have been creating custom policy with sepolicy-generate and one of the artefacts created is a SPEC file. When I run the same command on EL8 I don't get the SPEC file. According to the manpage on EL8 it should still be creating the SPEC file.

Is there some dependency that must be installed to enable this feature? Or what am I missing?

On EL7

```
$ sepolicy generate --init -n foo /usr/sbin/foo
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, product-id, subscription-manager

***************************************
Warning /usr/sbin/foo does not exist
***************************************

Created the following files:
/home/agriffit/audit2/foo.te # Type Enforcement file
/home/agriffit/audit2/foo.if # Interface file
/home/agriffit/audit2/foo.fc # File Contexts file
/home/agriffit/audit2/foo_selinux.spec # Spec file
/home/agriffit/audit2/foo.sh # Setup Script
```

On EL8

```
$ sepolicy generate --init -n foo /usr/sbin/foo

***************************************
Warning /usr/sbin/foo does not exist
***************************************

Created the following files:
/home/agriffit/test/foo.te # Type Enforcement file
/home/agriffit/test/foo.if # Interface file
/home/agriffit/test/foo.fc # File Contexts file
/home/agriffit/test/foo.sh # Setup Script
```

Comment: Same command works in EL9. Starting to think it's an EL8 bug.

Comment: Can you share which EL8 version have you tested above, add `uname -a` result?